# Continue from top in SQL SERVER Cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In C# language we use `continue` statement in a loop to move to next iteration. But in using Cursor in TSQL how can I perform the same. Let say I have,

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT age, name, color FROM table; 
DECLARE @myName VARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @myAge INT;
DECLARE @myFavoriteColor VARCHAR(40);
OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @myName, @myAge, @myFavoriteColor;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       --Do stuff 
       IF @myAge=1
       BEGIN
          -- Use continue here
       END    
       --Do stuff 


       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @myName, @myAge, @myFavoriteColor;
END;
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

Comment: Of course you realize that it is bad practice to use cursors if there is a set-based way to do the task, right?  Cursors are performance killers.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`CONTINUE` does go back to the start of the `WHILE` loop, but it's not exactly like in C#, since the cursor looping idiom in T-SQL is broken into two separate statements, and the `WHILE` is the second of them - the cleanest, requiring the least repetition, may be our old friend [`GOTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180188.aspx):

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT age, name, color FROM table; 
DECLARE @myName VARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @myAge INT;
DECLARE @myFavoriteColor VARCHAR(40);
OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @myName, @myAge, @myFavoriteColor;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       --Do stuff 
       IF @myAge=1
       BEGIN
          Goto Cont
       END    
       --Do stuff 

Cont:
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @myName, @myAge, @myFavoriteColor;
END;
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

Comment: Oh this one is also looks great. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

you can use CONTINUE in this manner

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT age, name, color FROM table; 
DECLARE @myName VARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @myAge INT;
DECLARE @myFavoriteColor VARCHAR(40);
OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @myName, @myAge, @myFavoriteColor;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       --Do stuff 
       IF @myAge=1
       BEGIN

           FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @myName, @myAge, @myFavoriteColor;
           CONTINUE;
       END    
       --Do stuff 


       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @myName, @myAge, @myFavoriteColor;
END;
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE 
       @myName VARCHAR(256)
     , @myAge INT
     , @myFavoriteColor VARCHAR(40)

DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
     SELECT age, name, color 
     FROM [table]

OPEN db_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO 
       @myName
     , @myAge
     , @myFavoriteColor

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

       IF @myAge = 1 BEGIN

            FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO 
                   @myName
                 , @myAge
                 , @myFavoriteColor

       END    

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO 
            @myName
          , @myAge
          , @myFavoriteColor

END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: I think CONTINUE is not go to next iteration unlike in C#

Comment: @user960567 - here's the [Technet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174366.aspx) for it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I have combined  FETCH NEXT and Continue to make it work. Thanks.